# Master aggregator will not start after install issues

Tags: singlestore

I had some issues installing the community edition of MemSQL due to the fact one of my machines only had two cores. I installed a new processor with four cores but I'm still having issues staring MemSQL. Here is the log file output:

5-22 21:18:15 INFO: Log opened
00000074 2015-05-22 21:18:15  WARN: max_connections will be throttled from 100000 to 3896 because the system resource 'NOFILE' is limited to 4096
00000155 2015-05-22 21:18:15 ERROR: open('/var/lib/memsql-ops/data/installs/MI817e82c8195841a1b29c3220a800bcd3/data/Hal.pid', O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR) failed. Error Permission denied (13)
00000176 2015-05-22 21:18:15 ERROR: Failed to start MemSQL

I attempted to un-install and start over from scratch but the directions I have for un-install do not appear to work with the community version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the logfile you attached appears to be truncated, but the most common reason you see such an error is a permissions issue with your data directory.

The easiest way to uninstall is `memsql-ops uninstall`. It will print a command that you must run to delete the corresponding MemSQL nodes before the uninstall completes. There is no distinction between community and enterprise editions of MemSQL with respect to install/uninstall.

Comment: Cluster deleted, reinstalled, and is up and running. Thanks!